# Shifting a node when opening the keyboard

Tags: javascript, typescript, cocoscreator

If you click on the editbox, the keyboard opens. A toolbar is attached to the top of the node and when you call the keyboard, it moves up and goes off the screen. I want the toolbar to be fixed at the top and so that when the keyboard is called, everything except the toolbar goes away.

When a node moves away when the keyboard is called, its world coordinates, visible size and anchor do not change when moved. Or maybe I can somehow control the keyboard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.